# How to link an bucket at a distribution?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I can create a s3 Amazon bucket, and I can create a Cloudfront distribution, but the missing thing, is that I have no idea how to set the bucket into a distribution point?

How would I get my uploaded files to a bucket to be served via Cloudfront distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Create your S3 bucket
2 - Create a new CloudFront distribution
3 - Inside CloudFront, click in the Origin Settings > Origin Domain Name select the appropriate S3 bucket (the drop down list will have append .amazonaws.com to your bucket name)

I think that's it.

Once you've finished creating the distribution you'll get a domain name to use for your cloudflare assets.

Good luck![image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you meant to tag this as CloudFlare.  If yes, we have some tips about [CloudFlare and S3](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-) that might help relative to your CloudFlare DNS settings.

Comment: Nginx S3 proxy might be an alternative option: https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files